# How can link each tab to different aspx pages?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have a application to allow the user upload and download the files.  Because the security reason, I have separate the application to Upload.aspx and Download.aspx.

On the default page, I would like use tabs to display upload and download page.

I am very new in the .net world.  This might be a very stupid question, but is it possible using multiview to link to two different pages.  All the example I have seen so far, the multiview only show static page.

Can any experts give me some advice how should I approach this problem.

![sample images][1]

    
    
    
        function Upload() {
            top.content.location.href = "wox_upload.aspx";
        }

```
<div class="tabContents">
<asp:MultiView id="MultiView1" ActiveViewIndex="0" Runat="server">
    <asp:View ID="View1" runat="server">
        Upload.aspx
    </asp:View>
    <asp:View ID="View2" runat="server">
        Download.aspx
    </asp:View>
</asp:MultiView>
</div>    
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: As a side question, can you explain how having the upload and download items on separate "pages" increases security in any meaningful way?

Answer (score 1):

The whole point of a MultiView is to allow multiple views on the same page.  If you want your tabs to be different pages, then just use links and style them to look like tabs.

Edit: After looking at your examples again, it looks like you are trying to embed "pages" into the different views.  In this case, you can create a user control for each view and put instances of them where you have the aspx names in your example.

User Controls generate parts of pages instead of whole pages, and can be included in aspx pages.  Here are a couple of links to get you started:

[How to: Create an ASP.NET User Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/26db8ysc%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#Y500)

[How to: Include a User Control in an ASP.NET Web Page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbz9etab%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: Thank you so much for your suggestion.  I have Upload and Download page works (Upload.aspx and Download.aspx)  Could you kindly give me some example of how to create  the user control for each page.

Comment: Added links to get you started.